# Chromedriver only opens new tab and crashes when Chrome is already open

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am running some JUnit-tests that start a new Chromedriver instance. When Chrome is not yet running everything works as expected, but when Chrome is already running (either from the first test that is still running or if it is opened manually), the test only opens a new Tab with "data;" in the address bar and after some time an

> "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"

is thrown.

I am using Chrome 44 (fix, cannot update Chrome) and already tried different Selenium and Chromedriver versions...any idea what may cause Chromedriver to start a new Tab instead of a new window?

Comment: how are you invoking chromedriver please post your code also

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast reply. I tried both: new ChromeDriver() with setting the system property to the chromedriver.exe first, as well as running standalone: "java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\Daten\chromedriver.exe" and then connecting to it with RemoteWebDriver(url, capabilities) in my tests.

Comment: can you do one this its my guess not an accurate answer can you do a fresh reinstall of the chrome browser on your machine and then give it a try

Comment: Unfortunatley I am not allowed to do that...I don't have any admin rights, that is also why I can not update Chrome